# Bitshifting chars in c

Tags: c, types, bit-shift, bitmask

I'm trying to get the bytes from an int into a series of chars in a portable way across all little endian systems.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
  int i = 0xabcdef12;
  printf("i: %x\n", i);
  char a, b, c, d;
  a = (i >> 000) & 0xFF;
  b = (i >> 010) & 0xFF;
  c = (i >> 020) & 0xFF;
  d = (i >> 030) & 0xFF;
  printf("a b c d: %x %x %x %x\n", a , b, c, d);
  if(a == 0x12)
    printf("a is 0x12\n");
  if(b == 0xef)
    printf("b is 0xef\n");
  if(c == 0xcd)
    printf("c is 0xcd\n");
  if(d == 0xab)
    printf("d is 0xab\n");
  if(a == 0xffffff12)
    printf("a is 0x12\n");
  if(b == 0xffffffef)
    printf("b is 0xffffffef\n");
  if(c == 0xffffffcd)
    printf("c is 0xffffffcd\n");
  if(d == 0xffffffab)
    printf("d is 0xffffffab\n");
  return 0;
}
```

This piece of code compiles without any warning when using -Wall.

When run this gives:

```
i: abcdef12
a b c d: 12 ffffffef ffffffcd ffffffab
a is 0x12
b is 0xffffffef
c is 0xffffffcd
d is 0xffffffab
```

Here are some gcc prints:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:14
14    if(a == 0x12)
(gdb) p/x a
$1 = 0x12
(gdb) p/x b
$2 = 0xef
(gdb) p/x c
$3 = 0xcd
(gdb) p/x d
$4 = 0xab
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong. It would really help me understand what is going on if you could answer a few  of the following questions:

- How can a char have value greater than 0xff?
- What aren't the `& 0xff` bitmasks working?
- Why does gdb report the correct values?

And if anybody has a reliable (system independent, but endianess is not important) way of going from int to char[], that would be great.

Comment: Are you intentionally using octal literals?

Comment: "And if anybody has a reliable (system independent, but endianess is not important) way of going from int to char[], that would be great."

What about unions?

Comment: @DennisMeng -- unions are a great way to type-pun a pointer.  They are rather system-dependent though... if you make a union between an array of four unsigned char values, and an integer, then you can read out the bytes of the integer very conveniently; but your code will at the very least be dependent on the endianness of the computer, and possibly on other implementation details (you may need to use a `#pragma` to control padding).  I suggest shifting and masking for portable code, and a union plus test cases for code that should be as fast as possible.

Comment: @Mystical -- it's clear the octals are on purpose.  They represent the number of bits to shift 0, 1, 2, or 3 bytes; this cannot be an accident.  IMHO the octal literals are odd enough that I would appreciate a comment noting "octal literals".  I believe this is the first time I have ever seen octal literals outside of an old textbook, and I had to stare at them for at least ten or fifteen seconds before I figured them out.  When I have written similar code I just used 0, 8, 16, and 24 for the shift numbers; I think most people understand that.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that the endianness was going to be a problem (OP said it wasn't important, so I didn't worry).

As for the padding issue, I wasn't actually aware of any architectures for which that would be an issue (though that's mostly out of ignorance; most everything I've learned assumes I'm using x86). I'll agree that such an architecture would mean that the union idea isn't portable.

Comment: @DennisMeng -- the padding is optional extra space put in by the compiler.  On some architectures, addressing is faster if things are aligned properly, and on others you get a "bus error" unless things are aligned properly, so the compiler inserts extra space inside a `struct` or `union`.  For this case, it would likely not be a problem on most architectures... but on an ADI DSP architecture, the `union` trick won't work at all, because the native data size is 32 bits, so `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)`!  Both `int` and `char` are 32-bit on an ADI DSP.  Shifting and masking will still work.

Comment: Ah okay. Learned something new. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick fix.

Change:

```
char a, b, c, d;
```

to

```
unsigned char a, b, c, d;
```

The reason is that `char` is signed on your system. When you pass, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` into `printf()`, they get promoted to `int`. They are sign-extended. That's why you get all those leading `ff`s.

GDB is reporting the correct values because it is reading the `chars` directly. (and thus no integer promotion)

Comment: There exist some people who would rather [only perform bit-shift operations on unsigned types](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT13-C.+Use+bitwise+operators+only+on+unsigned+operands) to avoid having to think about arithmetic- vs logical shifts. And thus avoiding exactly what Mystical has pointed out.

Comment: And therefore, `i` should be made `unsigned`. As right-shift on signed types is technically implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks, Prashant, I didn't realise there were two types of shifting. (Also it didn't occur to me that 0xffffffef was not a huge number, but a small negative number.)

Answer (score 1):

During comparison, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are promoted as `int`. Since they are all `char`, the most significant bit is treated as sign bit. The promotion to `int` fills MSB to higher bits.

`0x12`'s MSB is 0, and `0xef`, `0xcd` and `0xab`'s MSB is 1. That's why after promotion you get `0x00000012` but `0xffffffef`, `0xffffffcd` and `0xffffffab`.

If you change

```
char a, b, c, d;
```

into

```
unsigned char a, b, c, d;
```

Then you can get what you expected.